# What happens a hapi server method with caching gets called concurrently?

Tags: node.js, caching, hapi.js

Suppose I have a server method

```
server.method('foo', foo, { cache: { expiresIn: ###; } });
```

and suppose the first call to foo takes 15 seconds.

What will hapi do if a second request calls server.methods.foo() a couple seconds after a first request calls it?

Comment: The short version of the answer for this question is, "Any concurrent calls to the first call would take 15 seconds. When the first call completes and its result is cached, all further calls will get the cached value."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the cache isn't stale, hapi will short-circuit the method and return the cached value. If it's stale, the `foo` method will run again, rehydrate the cache, and return the result.

Comment: But the cached value isn't available yet. And if a series of requests lined up, then the value would never be cached.

Comment: @Seth it would be cached from 15s after the first request.